# Mock scope method from ActiveRecord in Rails/RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an ActiveRecord class like:

```rb
class DBGroup < ActiveRecord:Base

# ...
  scope :example_method, -> { // does something }
# ...
end
```

And now I have another method in another class, something like

```rb
def method1
   do #open block for rescue method
     DBGroup
       .example_method
       .group(:some_column)
       .having("COUNT(*) > 5")
   rescue StandardError => e
     e
   end
end
```

And in RSpec I am testing kind of like:

```rb
it "my test, want to test rescue block"
   expect_any_instance_of(DBGroup).to receive(:example_method).and_raise(StandardError)
   expect{subject.method1}.to raise_error(StandardError)
end
```

But I am getting the error like:

`RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: DBGroup does not implement #example_method`

Answer (score 0):

Scopes are not instance methods, they are class methods, so you should not use `expect_instance_of`, but `expect`.

Also, you are rescuing the `StandardError` inside the method, so the method itself does not raise a `StandardError`. Actually, a `StandardError` is raised **inside** the method and it's rescued **inside** of it aswel and your test is all about what's happening at it's **exterior**.

I hope you can see the difference:

```rb
def method_that_raises_an_error
  raise(StandardError)
end

def method_that_returns_an_error
  raise(StandardError)
rescue StandardError => e
  e
end
```

As you can see, your code is more like the second. So, to test it you should do:

```rb
expect(DBGroup).to(receive(:example_method).and_raise(StandardError)

method1_return = subject.method1

expect(method1_return).to(be_instance_of(StandardError))
```

Comment: I edited the actual "example_method" it is actually a chained method. If I write your example, I get this `expected StandardError but nothing was raised` Not sure why...

Comment: Do you have a public repo so I can take a look at it? I tried to reproduce it, but it's working here.

Comment: Its a company repo sadly :/ I am wondering, should it be `expect` or `expect_any_instance_of(DBGroup)`? I imagine since I dont have a specific instance that it should be the latter

Comment: Since you are running a scope, it should be only expect, because scope are class methods, not instance methods. I saw your updated question and updated mine to match it.